# Can we set a static issuer in Identity Server 4?

Tags: authentication, identityserver4

The access token in response contains the following claims:

```
"alg": "RS256",
"kid": "143e829c2b57489969753ba4f8205979df0da988c640cffa5f1f4eda1b6e6aa4",
"typ": "JWT"
"nbf": 1481451903,
"exp": 1481455503,
"iss": "https://localhost:44350",
"aud": [ "https://localhost:44350/resources", "customAPI" ],
"client_id": "oauthClient",
"scope": [ "customAPI.read" ]
```

And here is the config to tell my application to use IdentityServer to authenticate

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(
    new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44350/",
            ApiName = "customAPI",
            ApiSecret = "secret",
            AllowedScopes = {"customAPI.full_access", "customAPI.read_only" },                
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false
        });
```

How do I allow the user to authenticate on different alias of the IdentityServer aside https://localhost:44350/ e.g : http://192.168.1.20:44350/?

As currently the token get from the latter domain is deemed as invalid on my client which has the Authority setting to the former domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a static issuer name when adding IdentityServer in the `ConfigureServices` method. It's on the options passed into `AddIdentityServer`.

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html

Comment: the link is broken. here is the working link https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html

Comment: and if i need to change it per client basis?

Comment: does this have to be a uri? Would a non-uri string work?

Comment: This IssuerUri parameter logically should be a Uri, but practically does not as it is just a string appearing in the token as '**iss**' and resulting discovery document. I've just tested this. IssuerUri = "foo" is appearing in the document as well as the token and it is accepted. (This is a major benefit for development environments and internal docker networks.) *Do note* that using an per-request URL allows you to see on what domain the authentication was done and can help in making production environments more secure that way.