# Blazor WA hosted - 401 Unauthorized on Azure AppService

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a simple Blazor app from template. You can inspect it here: https://blazorfun2.azurewebsites.net/ . FetchData page is only for authorized users, but when I authorize I get `401 Unauthorized error`. Under the Response header it shows this error:

> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://blazorfun2.azurewebsites.net' is invalid"

You can test that with `testmail@testmail.something` and `Error#2` password.

I don't have this error on local host.

I am using Azure app service, dotnet 5.0 on Linux.

It is solvable by changing `IssuerUri` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581536/can-we-set-a-static-issuer-in-identity-server-4)), but I guess it's not the best option..

```cs
//Main method in Program.cs in Client: 
 var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
 builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

 builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorPlaygroundFun.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
     .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

 // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
 builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("BlazorPlaygroundFun.ServerAPI"));

 builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

 await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

```cs
//startup.cs in server project:
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages();
```

What is wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306175/bearer-error-invalid-token-error-description-the-issuer-is-invalid)? Else, did you check [the other questions and answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Bearer+error+invalid_token+error_description+The+issuer+is+invalid)?

Comment: These questions are related, yes. But not to the blazor and not to simple app that is just template.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

*When you log in successfully, call*

```
var token = await TokenProvider.GetTokenAsync();
```

*method to get jwt token.*

Then in Fetch Data, bring the jwt token in header, which will solve your problem.

**For more details, please check the related post.**

Thanks for [enet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152891/enet)'s answer.

**[Blazor WebAssembly 401 Unauthorized even when I am authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62841969/blazor-webassembly-401-unauthorized-even-when-i-am-authorized)**

Comment: Changing issuer uri seamed like a bad option. But this one isn't better - I have to edit every authorized page. I do not understand why it works only on localhost..